# Mount secondary partition on Hyper-V Server guest

Tags: virtual-machines, mount, partition, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

My Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 box has 2 partitions, one for the OS and a second for data. Can I configure my guest virtual machines to have access to that data partition? Preferably so that the guest OS sees it as a physical drive, not a mounted network share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You can assign DRIVES (Physical) to machiens a drives, but not partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "fixed" VHD that fills the entire volume.  Then you can assign that to the VM.  This will have the exact same behavior as passing the partition through to a VM.

Comment: Could I share that VHD across multiple guests or could only 1 guest mount it at a time?

Comment: Only one guest can mount it.  If you want to share, you have to use an iSCSI target.